# Entity framework supported databases

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework

I'm going to make a end-user desktop application, so I need a relative small database, such as Firebird or SqlLite. Does the Entity Framework 4 support other databases than SQL Server?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[ADO.NET Data Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dd363565.aspx) on MSDN lists several third party data providers for ADO.NET. [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/index.php?op=files&id=netprovider) and [SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) both look like what you are after, and both include Entity Framework 3.5 support (though I can't see any mention of EF4 support).

Comment: Good and bad news for me, I thought that I were forced to use NHibernate. Now it seems I can use both, so one more decision to make, but that's another question :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework supports these database providers:

- MS SQL Server
- SQLLite
- MySQl
- Oracle
- PostgreSQL
- Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS)
- Informix