# What database we have to use if i want to use Entity Framework instead of linq-to-sql

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, relational-database

I am new to entity framework. I wanna use entity framework, but I am confused which database i have to create like sql or something else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198573/entity-framework-supported-databases.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework is database independent, for a list of providers see here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dd363565.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If an ADO.NET Data Provider exists for your database - then you may use it with Entity Framework.

A list (maybe not full) of existing ADO.NET Providers you may find [in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dd363565.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you ask about supported databases - 
go to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework and look 
**Entity Framework ADO.NET providers**

Also you can use the same database that you use with Linq to SQL